# Android Cancel Async task when back pressed

Tags: android

I am loading video from async task. When video took too long to load then back press to cancel.

My code here

```
public class LiveStreaming extends AppCompatActivity {

VideoView videoView;
private myAsync sync;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_streaming);


    String videourl = getIntent().getStringExtra("Link");
    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoStreaming);
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "",
            "Loading TV...", true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    // progressDialog.dismiss();
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    Uri video = Uri.parse(videourl);// insert video url
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.requestFocus();

    sync = new myAsync();
    sync.execute();
    // PlayVideo();
}


private class myAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    int duration = 0;
    int current = 0;
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        running = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();

    videoView.start();
                duration = videoView.getDuration();
            }
        });

        do {

            current = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
            System.out.println("duration - " + duration + " current- "
                    + current);

            if (sync.isCancelled())
                break;

        }

        while (current != duration || current == 0);

        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (sync!=null){
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

}

I debugged my app.

When back pressed then method wasn't called. I don't know what is the problem

Thank you

Comment: use sync.cancel method to stop asynchtask

Comment: @ Divyesh Patel I used it already. My problem is when back button pressed. the method onBackPressed wasn't called

Comment: please refer to answer below . Upvote if it helped you.Thanks

Comment: its because of your if condition , your sync task would be null

Comment: try this sync.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING

Answer (score 1):

remove  `super.onBackPressed();` for `onBackPressed()` to work.And to cancel the async you can call `sync.cancel()`

Comment: What is the problem when back button pressed. the method wasn't called?

Comment: did it work?? . You are calling default functionality of onBackpressed by calling super.onBackpressed(); which usually finish the current activity and returns without executing the next steps in onBackpressed override method.

Comment: No onBackPressed method not called at all.

Comment: is dialog active when pressed back button.

Comment: Oh Finally I found my mistake. In my codeI give progressdialog.setCancelable(false). and changed to true. Now it works Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your async task in your activity.

```
private YourAsyncTask mTask;
```

Instantiate your async task where you want to use

```
mTask = new YourAsyncTask().execute();
```

And then cancel where you want to stop the task

```
mTask.cancel(true);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What is the problem when back button pressed. the method wasn't called?

Comment: this.finish(); finishes activity , you have to stop the task.

Comment: instead of this.finish(); use sync.cancel(true);

Comment: @ Abdul Kawee Yes I want to finish the activity when back pressed. But why method onBackPressed wasn't called?

Comment: When I press back button Nothing happened

Comment: I mistakenly commented on your question , check those comments it has answes